# How is the phase degradation of concrete modeled?

Tags: phase-transitions, macroscopic-materials, materials-engineering

Acid attack in concrete is a problem in sewage structures.

The phases degrade with the pH change at different pH values. The conditions in sewers is complex: The presence of a combination of acids, temperature variation, flow velocity changes, and the effects of bacteria make its study very complicated.

What techniques are used to model the degradation of concrete?

Comment: It's on Twitter: https://twitter.com/StackMatter/status/1272708930704150529 Re-tweet to get more attention.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because: This is another case where the user sign up, asked the question, and then never ever signed back in. We don't want someone to spend precious time doing research and writing up a potentially detailed/thorough answer only to find out the user was never going to come back to accept it or upvote it.   It also seems to be off-topic enough from the current community we have, such that it might never get an answer anyway. It's just hurting our % answered stat.